# Can't run catkin make for Arlo packages

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am receiving 'could not find a package configuration file provided by "PACKAGE_NAME" with any of the the following names' errors.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VMWare Workstation 12 Pro and ROS Indigo.

I have tried manually installing the packages but eventually i get to a package called "ceres" and can't progress any further.

I have also tried removing and reinstalling ROS Indigo and have not seen any results.

Edit:
Sorry, my bad.

The arlo platform is a base for a robot. I am using the parallax propeller board micro controller
https://www.parallax.com/product/arlo-robotic-platform-system

I'm trying to compile some packages from the indigo branch of this repository.
https://github.com/chrisl8/ArloBot

Essentially the packages are turtlebot code rejigged for the propeller board

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269157/can%27t-run-catkin-make-for-arlo-packages/) by [petherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31626/petherman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-20**:
We don't know what the "Arlo packages" are.

If you refer to something, please *always* include (a) link(s) to what you are referring to.

**Comment by [petherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31626/petherman/) on 2017-08-20**:
My bad, I have updated the description

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-20**:
Seeing as `chrisl8/ArloBot` has an issue tracker I would suggest you post your problem there. ROS Answers is a Q&A platform for (general) ROS questions about commonly used pkgs. Posting your question here is ok, but I expect that you'll get a more helpful answer from the pkg author than here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-20**:
And for any future questions you may post on ROS Answers: just stating "I'm receiving an error" and "I can't progress" is not really helpful. We can't see what you see (on your console), so just copy-paste error text *verbatim* into ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-20**:
.. your question please. Use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format such text properly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-20**:
[chrisl8/ArloBot#16](https://github.com/chrisl8/ArloBot/issues/16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I am the owner of the Arlo package. I am ChrisL8.

The solution is to add two more packages before running the install or cmake:

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-geodesy 
sudo apt install libceres-dev
```

I will go ahead and add those two packages to the install now.

Sorry for the slow response, I actually found this message while looking for the solution to the issue.

---

Originally posted by [ChrisL8](https://answers.ros.org/users/19020/chrisl8/) with karma: 241 on 2018-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0